# Microsoft Dynamics CRM run script (or something similar) in background

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, workflow, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

I wrote a script that adds the values of field A and field B. It then writes the result in field C.

My problem now is that, as I'm using a script, it only runs if I the form is open. However, I need to run it whenever field A or field B changes, regardless whether the form is open or not. For example, if a workflow changes the value of field A in the background, I need the script to calculate the new value of field C in the background as well.

I know that scripts only run on forms. That's why I'm looking for an alternative for scripts. I am aware that I could normally solve this by using a workflow, but I can't access field A through the workflow (it's a calculated field).

Are there any other possibilities?

Comment: Why not also using a calculated field for C?

Comment: Field A is calculated so it doesn't really "change". Some other field or fields change and cause the result of the calculation to be different. That other field (or fields) should be your trigger for a server side workflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find that for custom calculations the following approach is effective and doesn't require much effort to implement and mantain:

- Create an ACTION (let's call it new_action) without any steps
- Create a PLUGIN which does the math you want, register it to the new_action message
- Identify all the Simple fields involved
- Create a workflow for each entity where you found the fields, set it to run on Update of the Simple fields you identified in that entity
- The workflows should all be the same and the only step would be EXECUTE ACTION -> new_action

The end result is this behavior:

Simple field involved in your math changes -> Workflow starts -> Action starts -> Plugin does the math

NOTE: I usually make the action Unbound and "hand-craft" the data received by both the action and the plugin, but I glossed over this aspect because the approach itself stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use CRM plugin. It works on server side so it will run whenever fields values will change (user interface, workflow, system process, CRM API call, etc.).

Detailed information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328263.aspx

Answer (score 0):

1.Create an update message plugin with filtering attribute as A and B,
This will fire only when your form is updated and also only when attribute A and B has changed on that form.
2.write your logic in your plugin
3. choose async and sync depending on how frequent the changes are on A and B, ideally, I will use sync so that my value of C gets updated and be in sync all the time w.r.t A and B.